# Maven sure-fire-report name change not working

Tags: maven, report, rename, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using Maven Sure fire plugin to generate report for my selenium TESTNG test suites.
After the test, it generates the output in the location ..\target\local\surefire-reports.
The name of the report is emailable-report.html.
I saw that we can chnage the name of the report by passing  in Pom.xml.
Below in the section in pom.xml.
But I don't see the name changed after the report is generated. Am I missing something or are there any other way to change the name of 'emailable-report.html'

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <outputName>desired_name</outputName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only use `maven-surefire-report-plugin` in your POM, then yes, the `outputName` parameter is ignored.

If you also add `maven-site-plugin` to your list of build plug-ins, then you will see the effect of using the `outputName` parameter.

So, for example:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-M2</version>
            <configuration>
                <locales>en</locales>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
...
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputName>emailable-report</outputName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

When you do this, you will still continue to see a file called `surefire-report.html` being created - but now you will also see `emailable-report.html` as a separate file.

Both these files are in your project's `/target/site/` directory.

They contain the same reporting statistics.

---

There is one difference between the 2 files: The `emailable-report.html` file is part of the Maven project web site - and therefore it contains navigation links similar to those shown in [this official example](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html).

Which links you see depends on how you have configured your Maven project web site.

In my case, it only shows links to the SureFire report and the JavaDocs.

But you may prefer to stick with the original `surefire-report.html` file, because of this, and just rename it to whatever you want.